# Counting JSON leaf nodes

Tags: python, json, recursion, count, yield

I'd like to count the number of leaf (i.e. only those keys that have no further child elements) nodes in a JSON structure.

I can't find anything obvious to do this, so have been trying to write a function, but am struggling to find one that works, without using a global variable.

This is what I have so far:

```
def count_leafs(nested):
  is isinstance(nested, Mapping):
    for k, v in nested.items():
      if isinstance(v, Mapping):
        for i_k, i_v in count_leafs(v):
          yield i_k, i_v
      elif isinstance(v, MutableSequence):
        for i_k in v:
          for i_i_k, i_i_v in i_k.items():
            count_leafs(i_i_v)
      else:
        yield k, v
  elif isinstance(nested, MutableSequence):
    for k in nested:
      count_leafs(k)


for k,v in count_leafs(json):
 leaf_count += 1
```

Which doesn't really work as some non leaf nodes are counted, and it's not recursing all the way down into some structures.

Comment: Sorry... **how** is this off-topic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I prefer non-recursive solutions over recursive ones. My algorithm works like this:

1. Initialize the queue and place the json object into it
2. Loop while the queue is not empty
3. Get one node from the queue

   - If it is a Mapping, add all the values to the queue for later processing
   - If it is a sequence or a set (be careful: strings are sequence, too--we need to test against it), we add all the elements to the queue for later processing
   - If the it is none of the above, count it

Here is the code:

```
from collections import Mapping, Sequence, Set, deque

def count_leaves(nested):
    queue = deque([nested])
    count = 0
    while queue:
        node = queue.popleft()
        if isinstance(node, Mapping):
            queue.extend(node.values())
        elif isinstance(node, (Sequence, Set)) and not isinstance(node, basestring):
            queue.extend(node)
        else:
            count += 1

    return count
```

Comment: Replaced basestring with str as on Python3, cheers Hai.

Comment: Cool. I learned something new.

Answer (score 2):

Your pseudo-code is over-complicated and buggy. I would also suggest you write code that follows the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) closely, for both yourself and others reading the code you write.

Anyway, as a test case, suppose you had some JSON data like this:

```
json_data = {
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "answer": 42,
        "boolean": True,
        "nada": None,
        "GlossDiv": {
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "GlossSeeAlso": [
                            "GML",
                            "XML"
                        ],
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup "
                                "languages such as DocBook."
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "ID": "SGML"
                }
            },
            "title": "S"
        }
    }
}
```

You can recursively count the leaves like this:

```
from collections import Mapping, MutableSequence

def count_leaves(json_obj):

    def leaf_iterator(json_obj):
        if isinstance(json_obj, Mapping):
            for v in json_obj.values():
                for obj in leaf_iterator(v):
                    yield obj
        elif isinstance(json_obj, MutableSequence):
            for v in json_obj:
                for obj in leaf_iterator(v):
                    yield obj
        else:
            yield json_obj

    return sum(1 for leaf in leaf_iterator(json_obj))

leaf_count = count_leaves(json_data)
print('leaf count: {}'.format(leaf_count))  # -> leaf_count: 14
```

I nested the `leaf_iterator()` generator inside the leaf counting function, but it could also be defined outside if it should it prove useful in a larger context. The code in it could be simplified even further in Python 3 by using a [`yield from`*`<expression>`*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yieldexpr) which was introduced in Python version 3.3.

Comment: In the return statement, I believe you mean `json_obj`, not `json_data`

Comment: @HaiVu: Yes, I did — fixed. Thank you. Good catch, although at that point they're always both the same thing, so it wasn't noticeable and didn't change the results (in the test code anyway).